# a href not opening on focused div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using TailwindCSS. I have an SVG that when clicked, displays an `absolute` component.

```js
<div tabIndex={0} className="relative group">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="w-5 h-5 text-indigo-600 outline-none cursor-pointer" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
      <path d="M9.663 17h4.673M12 3v1m6.364 1.636l-.707.707M21 12h-1M4 12H3m3.343-5.657l-.707-.707m2.828 9.9a5 5 0 117.072 0l-.548.547A3.374 3.374 0 0014 18.469V19a2 2 0 11-4 0v-.531c0-.895-.356-1.754-.988-2.386l-.548-.547z" />
   </svg>
   <div className="absolute top-0 z-50 hidden h-auto max-w-sm overflow-y-auto text-left transform translate-x-full bg-white rounded shadow-2xl max-h-60 group-focus:flex min-w-screen -right-full">
      <div className="flex flex-col">
         <p className="px-4 py-2 font-bold text-indigo-600 bg-indigo-100 text center">Additional Announcements</p>
         <div className="flex flex-col px-4 divide-y divide-gray-200">
            <div className="flex flex-col py-2 text-gray-700">
               <span className="font-medium text-gray-700">{existingAnnLocalisedDate}</span>
               <div className="flex">
                  <a className="leading-snug cursor-pointer hover:underline" href={ann.url} onClick={() => Logger({ key: "ANNOUNCEMENT_CLICKED" })} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                    {ann.headline}
                  </a>
                  { ann.isPriceSensitive && (
                  <span className="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-auto h-auto ml-1 font-medium text-center cursor-default" title="Price sensitive">
                    &#128176;
                  </span>
                  )}
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works as expected, however when I click an `<a href="" />` element, it doesn't actually open that link - it just drops the `focus` on that component. How can I make it so that not only does it drop the focus, but it also opens the link in a new tab, as the code suggests?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried <a href="" _target="blank" /> (or whatever the syntax), maybe that does the trick

Comment: that's already there?

Comment: is it? 
You probably overwriting the behaviour of href with your onclick method, you will have to add some javascript logic to do the same as href (window.... whatever the syntax is for that).